# Admin panel for webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm implementing an ecommerce app on Google App Engine, using the webapp2 framework.

The idea is that apart from the app, there should be some sort of admin panel, similar to what Django provides, that will let my clients upload products, manage users and so on. Is there some kind of package, that would automatically generate the admin modules and views for me, the way [Flask-Admin](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) does?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could use Flask-Admin? Or Django? And still use webapp2

Comment: I've tried using Flask-Admin - the trouble is, it works on SQLAlchemy or MongoEngine, but fails with Google's Datastore. A lot of my code's already done - the shopping cart, payments, and so on, so switching to Django would be quite cumbersome..

Comment: Gotya. This snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/59/ seems to indicate admin is compatable with app engine, in that it mixes GAE and flask-admin code. I don't have anything specific on why it does not work in app engine, perhaps that could be a seperate question as it's probably the easiest option for you?

Comment: Wow. Honestly, I haven't tried this out. Maybe I should. On the off-chance that it doesn't work, is there a forms library that I could use to quickly hack the admin panel together?

Comment: Hey, I think this might do the trick: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.appengine

Comment: Yes, I've used and recommend that exact thing :) but for a small number of form fields I've found it's often easier to create by hand. but if you have lots of fields in your model/lots of models then it's perfect.

Comment: Oh, great! There are atleast 6 fields in every model. Sometimes more. I think I'll use this then - thanks! :D

Comment: Would you like to add this as an answer or something?

Comment: Indeed, for the next person along an answer will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/59 seems to indicate admin is compatable with app engine, in that it mixes GAE and flask-admin code.

As an alternative WTForms can be used to generate forms directly from models and feed the data back into the DB and it has a GAE component built in already: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.appengine

Comment: The first part of your answer is wrong and misleading. The snippet is about admin blueprint.`import admin` has nothing to do with flask-admin.

Comment: if you want to suggest an edit please do so, or provide an alternative answer which I'll happily upvote.